# how to create two document types in one elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have CRM data that I am trying to index into elastic search, 1. case entity 2. task entity. here one case can have more than one task with case id as a reference. how can I create different document types to store both case and task under the same elastic search index?

I am trying in elastic search 7.2

Comment: why you want to create just 1 index, simply create 2 indices, one for cases and one for task with parent-child relationship https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: i have looked into it already but bit confused with this explanation "The join datatype is a special field that creates parent/child relation within documents of the same index"